# Can't access a property inside extension in Swift 2.1

Tags: ios, swift

I can't access a property `let selectedCategory` declared in extension of the same class

I get `Use of unresolved identifier 'selectedCategory'` if I try to access it inside the class. How can I access it?

```
extension CreateRecipeVC: RecipeCategoryTableVCDelegate {
    func categoryController(controller: RecipeCategoryTableVC, didSelectCategory category: String) {
        let selectedCategory = category

        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

        let cell = RecipeCategoryCell()
        cell.configureSelectedCategoryCell(selectedCategory)
    }
}


class CreateRecipeVC: UIViewController, ... {

    if selectedCategory != nil {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't `selectedCategory` a variable **inside** `categoryController(didSelectCategory:)`?

Comment: It is actually...but moving it outside the function, I also get an error `Extensions may not contain stored properties`

Comment: And this is already the answer: you cannot set a property in an extension. You would have to subclass.

Answer (score 3):

In your code `selectedCategory`is a local variable, not a property. It's only visible to the scope of the function it is declared in.

If you want it to be a property, you'll need to declare it in the main definition of your class. At the moment, stored properties are not supported in extensions. This is a technical limitation of the way classes and structs are created. IT's easy to add new methods to a class's vtable, but it is hard to increase the size of the instance's storage.